# Correct movement of rectangular blocks inside canvas in fabric.js library

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas, fabricjs

It is necessary to make it so that blocks regardless of width and length do not overlap with each other and do not go beyond the borders of the canvas when moving and when resizing. Blocks can be either full width or full length, and with the side of the minimum cell.
If anyone has a solution or at least the direction in which to move I will be very happy

Here is my code. It does not work quite correctly, because in some cases it jumps to the wrong zones behind the canvas or inside another block.

```js
const canvasSize = { width: 1923, height: 1083 }
const cellDimensions = { width: 120, height: 120 }
const borderStrokeWidth = 3
const objectTypes = {
    frame: 'frame',
    gridPoint: 'point',
    gridLine: 'line',
}

const initialFramesList = [
    {
        top: 120,
        left: 120,
        width: 240,
        height: 480,
    },
    {
        top: 120,
        left: 600,
        width: 480,
        height: 720,
    },
]

let drawingCanvas

initCanvas()
initFrames(initialFramesList)

function initCanvas(id = 'canvas') {
    let startX
    let startY
    let endX
    let endY
    let activeFrame

    drawingCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(id, {
        height: canvasSize.height + borderStrokeWidth,
        width: canvasSize.width + borderStrokeWidth,
        hoverCursor: 'default',
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        selection: false,
    })

    const onClickPoint = (e) => {
        const isGridPoint = e.target?.type === objectTypes.gridPoint

        if (isGridPoint && !activeFrame) {
            const { top: y, left: x, width: d } = e.target
            const r = d / 2
            startX = x + r
            startY = y + r
            activeFrame = createFrame({ x: startX, y: startY })
            drawingCanvas.add(activeFrame)
        } else if (activeFrame) {
            startX = null
            startY = null
            endX = null
            endY = null
            activeFrame.setCoords()
            activeFrame = null
            drawingCanvas.renderAll()
        }
    }

    const widgetsLoop = (fn) => {
        const widgets = drawingCanvas.getObjects(objectTypes.frame)
        widgets.forEach((obj) => {
            fn(obj)
        })
    }

    const getAbsolutePosition = (el) => {
        return el.group
            ? { x: el.group.left, y: el.group.top }
            : { x: el.left, y: el.top }
    }

    const hasIntersection = (target, obj) => {
        const { x: targetLeft, y: targetTop } = getAbsolutePosition(target)
        const { x: objLeft, y: objTop } = getAbsolutePosition(obj)
        const {
            width: targetWidth,
            height: targetHeight,
            originX: targetOriginX,
            originY: targetOriginY,
        } = target
        const { width: objWidth, height: objHeight } = obj

        const rectLeftCorrect =
            targetOriginX === 'right'
                ? targetLeft - targetWidth - borderStrokeWidth
                : targetLeft
        const rectTopCorrect =
            targetOriginY === 'bottom'
                ? targetTop - targetHeight - borderStrokeWidth
                : targetTop

        const xIntersection =
            rectLeftCorrect + targetWidth > objLeft &&
            rectLeftCorrect < objLeft + objWidth
        const yIntersection =
            rectTopCorrect + targetHeight > objTop &&
            rectTopCorrect < objTop + objHeight

        return xIntersection && yIntersection
    }

    const limitFrameMoving = (target) => {
        const { width: screenW, height: screenH } = canvasSize
        const { x: rectLeft, y: rectTop } = getAbsolutePosition(target)
        const {
            originX: targetOriginX,
            originY: targetOriginY,
            width: targetW,
            height: targetH,
        } = target
        const rectLeftCorrect =
            targetOriginX === 'right'
                ? rectLeft - targetW - borderStrokeWidth
                : rectLeft
        const rectTopCorrect =
            targetOriginY === 'bottom'
                ? rectTop - targetH - borderStrokeWidth
                : rectTop

        if (rectLeftCorrect < 0) {
            target.set({ left: 0 })
        } else if (rectLeftCorrect + targetW > screenW) {
            target.set({ left: screenW - targetW })
        }

        if (rectTopCorrect < 0) {
            target.set({ top: 0 })
        } else if (rectTopCorrect + targetH > screenH) {
            target.set({ top: screenH - targetH })
        }
    }

    const setValidSize = (target) => {
        const { width: cellW, height: cellH } = cellDimensions

        widgetsLoop((obj) => {
            if (obj === target) {
                return
            }

            if (hasIntersection(target, obj)) {
                const { x: rectLeft, y: rectTop } = getAbsolutePosition(target)
                const { x: objLeft, y: objTop } = getAbsolutePosition(obj)
                const { originX: targetOriginX, originY: targetOriginY } =
                    target
                const { width: objWidth, height: objHeight } = obj

                const rectLeftCorrect =
                    targetOriginX === 'right'
                        ? rectLeft - objWidth - borderStrokeWidth
                        : rectLeft
                const rectTopCorrect =
                    targetOriginY === 'bottom'
                        ? rectTop - objHeight - borderStrokeWidth
                        : rectTop

                const dx = Math.abs(rectLeftCorrect - objLeft)
                const dy = Math.abs(rectTopCorrect - objTop)

                if (dx > dy && target.width > dx) {
                    target.set({ width: dx, cellY: dx / cellW })
                } else if (dx < dy && target.height > dy) {
                    target.set({ height: dy, cellY: dy / cellH })
                }
            }
        })
    }

    const setValidPosition = (target) => {
        widgetsLoop((obj) => {
            if (obj === target) {
                return
            }

            limitFrameMoving(target)

            if (hasIntersection(target, obj)) {
                const dx = Math.abs(target.left - obj.left)
                const dy = Math.abs(target.top - obj.top)
                if (dx > dy) {
                    target.set({ left: obj.left - target.width })
                    if (target.left < 0) {
                        target.set({ left: obj.left + obj.width })
                    }
                } else {
                    target.set({ top: obj.top - target.height })
                    if (target.top < 0) {
                        target.set({ top: obj.top + obj.height })
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        drawingCanvas.renderAll()
    }

    drawingCanvas.on('mouse:over', (e) => {
        if (e.target?.type === objectTypes.gridPoint) {
            drawingCanvas.bringToFront(e.target)
            e.target.set('opacity', 1)
            drawingCanvas.renderAll()
        }
    })

    drawingCanvas.on('mouse:out', (e) => {
        if (e.target?.type === objectTypes.gridPoint) {
            e.target.set('opacity', 0)
            drawingCanvas.renderAll()
        }
    })

    drawingCanvas.on('mouse:down', (e) => {
        onClickPoint(e)
    })

    drawingCanvas.on('mouse:move', (e) => {
        if (!activeFrame) {
            return
        }

        const { width: cellW, height: cellH } = cellDimensions
        const pointerX = Math.floor(e.pointer.x / cellW) * cellW
        const pointerY = Math.floor(e.pointer.y / cellH) * cellH

        const width = pointerX - startX + cellW
        const height = pointerY - startY + cellH

        if (pointerX >= startX) {
            activeFrame.set({ width, cellX: width / cellW })
        }

        if (pointerY >= startY) {
            activeFrame.set({ height, cellY: height / cellH })
        }

        setValidSize(activeFrame)

        drawingCanvas.renderAll()
    })

    drawingCanvas.on('object:scaling', (e) => {
        const target = e.target
        const { width: cellW, height: cellH } = cellDimensions
        const width = Math.round((target.width * target.scaleX) / cellW) * cellW
        const height =
            Math.round((target.height * target.scaleY) / cellH) * cellH
        const { originX, originY, corner } = e.transform
        const { y: top, x: left } = target.getPointByOrigin(originX, originY)

        target.set({
            originX,
            originY,
            left,
            top,
            scaleX: 1,
            scaleY: 1,
            width: width > cellW ? width : cellW,
            height: height > cellH ? height : cellH,
            cellX: width / cellW,
            cellY: height / cellH,
            lockScalingFlip: true,
        })

        setValidSize(target)
    })

    drawingCanvas.on('object:moving', (e) => {
        const target = e.target
        const { width: cellW, height: cellH } = cellDimensions
        const left = Math.floor(target.left / cellW) * cellW
        const top = Math.floor(target.top / cellH) * cellH
        target.set({
            left,
            top,
        })
        setValidPosition(target)
    })

    drawingCanvas.on('object:modified', (e) => {
        const obj = e.target
        const { y: top, x: left } = obj.getPointByOrigin('left', 'top')
        obj.set({ top, left, originX: 'left', originY: 'top' })
        drawingCanvas.renderAll()
    })

    drawGrid()
}

function drawGrid() {
    const { width: colSize, height: rowSize } = cellDimensions

    const makePoint = (x, y) => {
        const r = 8
        const point = new fabric.Rect({
            top: y - r,
            left: x - r,
            width: r * 2,
            height: r * 2,
            rx: 1,
            ry: 1,
            fill: 'black',
            hasControls: false,
            hasBorders: false,
            selectable: false,
            opacity: 0,
            type: objectTypes.gridPoint,
            hoverCursor: 'pointer',
        })

        drawingCanvas.add(point)
    }

    const drawLine = (params) => {
        const line = new fabric.Line(params, {
            stroke: 'yellow',
            borderStrokeWidth: borderStrokeWidth,
            selectable: false,
            evented: false,
            type: objectTypes.gridLine,
        })
        drawingCanvas.add(line)
    }

    const makeRows = () => {
        const rowsCount = canvasSize.height / rowSize
        for (let i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
            const y = i * rowSize
            drawLine([0, y, canvasSize.width, y])
        }
    }

    const makeCols = () => {
        const colsCount = canvasSize.width / colSize
        for (let i = 0; i < colsCount; i++) {
            const x = i * colSize
            drawLine([x, 0, x, canvasSize.height])
        }
    }

    const makePoints = () => {
        const rowsCount = canvasSize.height / rowSize
        const colsCount = canvasSize.width / colSize
        for (let i = 0; i < colsCount; i++) {
            const x = i * colSize
            for (let j = 0; j < rowsCount; j++) {
                const y = j * rowSize
                makePoint(x, y)
            }
        }
    }

    makeRows()
    makeCols()
    makePoints()
}

function initFrames(frames) {
    const { width: cellW, height: cellH } = cellDimensions
    frames.forEach(({ top, left, width, height }) => {
        const frame = createFrame(
            {
                x: left,
                y: top,
            },
            {
                width: width,
                height: height,
            }
        )
        frame.set({
            cellX: width / cellW,
            cellY: height / cellH,
            lockScalingFlip: true,
        })
        drawingCanvas.add(frame)
    })
}

function createFrame({ x, y }, { width, height } = { width: 0, height: 0 }) {
    const rect = new fabric.Rect({
        top: y,
        left: x,
        width,
        height,
        stroke: 'gray',
        borderStrokeWidth: borderStrokeWidth,
        fill: 'white',
        type: objectTypes.frame,
        strokeUniform: true,
        noScaleCache: false,
        objectCaching: false,
    })

    return rect
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Everything I've tried is listed in my code. The element rotation will not be used, I will exclude it from the library later.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `"in some cases it jumps to the wrong zones"` maybe provide some screenshoots of those cases

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that I think might be what you call a jump to the wrong zone.

[image]

We can see I'm moving the left block horizontally but it jumps down to the bottom...

So I'm just going to focus on that **horizontal movement problem**, and that alone...
Looking at your code you have `setValidPosition` and inside that there is a condition:
`if (hasIntersection(target, obj)) {`

I really could not understand your logic there, I think all that is needed there is set the position back to a known good state, there should not be any moving when there is an intersection.

Two things I will do:
First enable stateful on the canvas

```
drawingCanvas.stateful = true;
```

then change the setValidPosition to

```
const setValidPosition = (target) => {
  widgetsLoop((obj) => {
    if (obj === target) {
      return
    }
    if (hasIntersection(target, obj)) {
      target.set({ left: target._stateProperties.left, top: target._stateProperties.top })
    } else {
      target.saveState();
    }
  })
  drawingCanvas.renderAll()
}
```

Here is the result, I'm still moving the left block horizontally but we can see that while the mouse is over the second block there is not  jumping down like there was before
[image]

---

I removed some of your code to just focus on the movement and keep the code as small as possible, see working snippet below

```js
const canvasSize = { width: 520, height: 400 }
const cellDimensions = { width: 40, height: 40 }
const borderStrokeWidth = 3
const objectTypes = {frame: 'frame', gridPoint: 'point', gridLine: 'line'}

const initialFramesList = [
    {top: 40, left: 200, width: 80, height: 200},
    {top: 40, left: 40, width: 80, height: 120}
]

let drawingCanvas

initCanvas()
initFrames(initialFramesList)

function initCanvas(id = 'canvas') {
    let startX
    let startY
    let endX
    let endY
    let activeFrame

    drawingCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(id, {
        height: canvasSize.height + borderStrokeWidth,
        width: canvasSize.width + borderStrokeWidth,
        hoverCursor: 'default',
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        selection: false,
    })
    drawingCanvas.stateful = true;

    const widgetsLoop = (fn) => {
        const widgets = drawingCanvas.getObjects(objectTypes.frame)
        widgets.forEach((obj) => { fn(obj) })
    }

    const getAbsolutePosition = (el) => {
        return el.group
            ? { x: el.group.left, y: el.group.top }
            : { x: el.left, y: el.top }
    }

    const hasIntersection = (target, obj) => {
        const { x: targetLeft, y: targetTop } = getAbsolutePosition(target)
        const { x: objLeft, y: objTop } = getAbsolutePosition(obj)
        const {
            width: targetWidth,
            height: targetHeight,
            originX: targetOriginX,
            originY: targetOriginY,
        } = target
        const { width: objWidth, height: objHeight } = obj

        const rectLeftCorrect =
            targetOriginX === 'right'
                ? targetLeft - targetWidth - borderStrokeWidth
                : targetLeft
        const rectTopCorrect =
            targetOriginY === 'bottom'
                ? targetTop - targetHeight - borderStrokeWidth
                : targetTop

        const xIntersection =
            rectLeftCorrect + targetWidth > objLeft &&
            rectLeftCorrect < objLeft + objWidth
        const yIntersection =
            rectTopCorrect + targetHeight > objTop &&
            rectTopCorrect < objTop + objHeight
        
        return xIntersection && yIntersection
    }

    const setValidPosition = (target) => {
        widgetsLoop((obj) => {
            if (obj === target) {
                return
            }
            if (hasIntersection(target, obj)) {
                target.set({ 
                  left: target._stateProperties.left, 
                  top: target._stateProperties.top, })
            } else {
                target.saveState();
            }
        })
        drawingCanvas.renderAll()
    }

    drawingCanvas.on('mouse:over', (e) => {
        if (e.target?.type === objectTypes.gridPoint) {
            drawingCanvas.bringToFront(e.target)
            e.target.set('opacity', 1)
            drawingCanvas.renderAll()
        }
    })

    drawingCanvas.on('mouse:out', (e) => {
        if (e.target?.type === objectTypes.gridPoint) {
            e.target.set('opacity', 0)
            drawingCanvas.renderAll()
        }
    })

    drawingCanvas.on('object:moving', (e) => {
        const target = e.target
        const { width: cellW, height: cellH } = cellDimensions
        const left = Math.floor(target.left / cellW) * cellW
        const top = Math.floor(target.top / cellH) * cellH
        target.set({ left, top })
        setValidPosition(target)
    })

    drawingCanvas.on('object:modified', (e) => {
        const obj = e.target
        const { y: top, x: left } = obj.getPointByOrigin('left', 'top')
        obj.set({ top, left, originX: 'left', originY: 'top' })
        drawingCanvas.renderAll()
    })

    drawGrid()
}

function drawGrid() {
    const { width: colSize, height: rowSize } = cellDimensions

    const drawLine = (params) => {
        const line = new fabric.Line(params, {
            stroke: 'yellow',
            borderStrokeWidth: borderStrokeWidth,
            selectable: false,
            evented: false,
            type: objectTypes.gridLine,
        })
        drawingCanvas.add(line)
    }

    const makeRows = () => {
        const rowsCount = canvasSize.height / rowSize
        for (let i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
            const y = i * rowSize
            drawLine([0, y, canvasSize.width, y])
        }
    }

    const makeCols = () => {
        const colsCount = canvasSize.width / colSize
        for (let i = 0; i < colsCount; i++) {
            const x = i * colSize
            drawLine([x, 0, x, canvasSize.height])
        }
    }

    makeRows()
    makeCols()
}

function initFrames(frames) {
    const { width: cellW, height: cellH } = cellDimensions
    frames.forEach(({ top, left, width, height }) => {
        const frame = createFrame(
            { x: left, y: top },
            { width: width, height: height }
        )
        frame.set({
            cellX: width / cellW,
            cellY: height / cellH,
            lockScalingFlip: true,
        })
        drawingCanvas.add(frame)
    })
}

function createFrame({ x, y }, { width, height } = { width: 0, height: 0 }) {
    const rect = new fabric.Rect({
        top: y,
        left: x,
        width,
        height,
        stroke: 'gray',
        borderStrokeWidth: borderStrokeWidth,
        fill: 'white',
        type: objectTypes.frame,
        strokeUniform: true,
        noScaleCache: false,
        objectCaching: false,
    })
    drawingCanvas.setActiveObject(rect)
    return rect
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How else can I make sure it doesn't go beyond the canvas yet?

Comment: In addition I will write that my variant creates additional blocks from intersection points, which also form artifacts when multiple blocks are placed next to each other.

Comment: @SergeyF you have multiple questions, focus on one at time ... like I said in my answer I focus on the horizontal movement problem, you should ask separate questions for each issue

Comment: The movement of the blocks worked correctly as it searched for the closest point on either side, unfortunately my main issue is that the blocks intersect in a closed space, that's the problem. But thanks anyway. Also properties with underscores are private as far as I know and using them outside the class is not correct.

Comment: @SergeyF what do you mean "The movement of the blocks worked correctly" on the images i'm clearly showsng it is not correct, it jumps down when it should not move...

Comment: @SergeyF  please explain  "blocks intersect in a closed space"  can you add an animation showing that?

Comment: I added a variation on the wrong block intersection.

Answer (score 0):

I made a new arrangement of blocks. If there are more than two blocks, they start overlapping. I used your example as a basis. Thanks for your help.
[GIF example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzlLI.gif)

```js
const canvasSize = { width: 520, height: 400 }
const cellDimensions = { width: 40, height: 40 }
const borderStrokeWidth = 3
const objectTypes = {frame: 'frame', gridPoint: 'point', gridLine: 'line'}

const initialFramesList = [
  {
      top: 40,
      left: 80,
      width: 200,
      height: 40,
  },
  {
      top: 120,
      left: 200,
      width: 80,
      height: 120,
  },
  {
      top: 280,
      left: 0,
      width: 360,
      height: 80,
  },
  {
      top: 0,
      left: 360,
      width: 120,
      height: 400,
  },
]

let drawingCanvas

initCanvas()
initFrames(initialFramesList)

function initCanvas(id = 'canvas') {
    let startX
    let startY
    let endX
    let endY
    let activeFrame

    drawingCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(id, {
        height: canvasSize.height + borderStrokeWidth,
        width: canvasSize.width + borderStrokeWidth,
        hoverCursor: 'default',
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        selection: false,
    })
    drawingCanvas.stateful = true;

    const widgetsLoop = (fn) => {
        const widgets = drawingCanvas.getObjects(objectTypes.frame)
        widgets.forEach((obj) => { fn(obj) })
    }

    const getAbsolutePosition = (el) => {
        return el.group
            ? { x: el.group.left, y: el.group.top }
            : { x: el.left, y: el.top }
    }

    const limitFrameMoving = (target) => {
        const { width: screenW, height: screenH } = canvasSize
        const { x: rectLeft, y: rectTop } = getAbsolutePosition(target)
        const {
            originX: targetOriginX,
            originY: targetOriginY,
            width: targetW,
            height: targetH,
        } = target
        const rectLeftCorrect =
            targetOriginX === 'right'
                ? rectLeft - targetW - borderStrokeWidth
                : rectLeft
        const rectTopCorrect =
            targetOriginY === 'bottom'
                ? rectTop - targetH - borderStrokeWidth
                : rectTop

        if (rectLeftCorrect < 0) {
            target.set({ left: 0 })
        } else if (rectLeftCorrect + targetW > screenW) {
            target.set({ left: screenW - targetW })
        }

        if (rectTopCorrect < 0) {
            target.set({ top: 0 })
        } else if (rectTopCorrect + targetH > screenH) {
            target.set({ top: screenH - targetH })
        }
    }

    const hasIntersection = (target, obj) => {
        const { x: targetLeft, y: targetTop } = getAbsolutePosition(target)
        const { x: objLeft, y: objTop } = getAbsolutePosition(obj)
        const {
            width: targetWidth,
            height: targetHeight,
            originX: targetOriginX,
            originY: targetOriginY,
        } = target
        const { width: objWidth, height: objHeight } = obj

        const rectLeftCorrect =
            targetOriginX === 'right'
                ? targetLeft - targetWidth - borderStrokeWidth
                : targetLeft
        const rectTopCorrect =
            targetOriginY === 'bottom'
                ? targetTop - targetHeight - borderStrokeWidth
                : targetTop

        const xIntersection =
            rectLeftCorrect + targetWidth > objLeft &&
            rectLeftCorrect < objLeft + objWidth
        const yIntersection =
            rectTopCorrect + targetHeight > objTop &&
            rectTopCorrect < objTop + objHeight
        
        return xIntersection && yIntersection
    }

    const setValidPosition = (target) => {
        widgetsLoop((obj) => {
            if (obj === target) {
                return
            }
            limitFrameMoving(target)

            if (hasIntersection(target, obj)) {
                target.set({ 
                  left: target._stateProperties.left, 
                  top: target._stateProperties.top, })
            } else {
                target.saveState();
            }
        })
        drawingCanvas.renderAll()
    }

    drawingCanvas.on('mouse:over', (e) => {
        if (e.target?.type === objectTypes.gridPoint) {
            drawingCanvas.bringToFront(e.target)
            e.target.set('opacity', 1)
            drawingCanvas.renderAll()
        }
    })

    drawingCanvas.on('mouse:out', (e) => {
        if (e.target?.type === objectTypes.gridPoint) {
            e.target.set('opacity', 0)
            drawingCanvas.renderAll()
        }
    })

    drawingCanvas.on('object:moving', (e) => {
        const target = e.target
        const { width: cellW, height: cellH } = cellDimensions
        const left = Math.floor(target.left / cellW) * cellW
        const top = Math.floor(target.top / cellH) * cellH
        target.set({ left, top })
        setValidPosition(target)
    })

    drawingCanvas.on('object:modified', (e) => {
        const obj = e.target
        const { y: top, x: left } = obj.getPointByOrigin('left', 'top')
        obj.set({ top, left, originX: 'left', originY: 'top' })
        drawingCanvas.renderAll()
    })

    drawGrid()
}

function drawGrid() {
    const { width: colSize, height: rowSize } = cellDimensions

    const drawLine = (params) => {
        const line = new fabric.Line(params, {
            stroke: 'yellow',
            borderStrokeWidth: borderStrokeWidth,
            selectable: false,
            evented: false,
            type: objectTypes.gridLine,
        })
        drawingCanvas.add(line)
    }

    const makeRows = () => {
        const rowsCount = canvasSize.height / rowSize
        for (let i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
            const y = i * rowSize
            drawLine([0, y, canvasSize.width, y])
        }
    }

    const makeCols = () => {
        const colsCount = canvasSize.width / colSize
        for (let i = 0; i < colsCount; i++) {
            const x = i * colSize
            drawLine([x, 0, x, canvasSize.height])
        }
    }

    makeRows()
    makeCols()
}

function initFrames(frames) {
    const { width: cellW, height: cellH } = cellDimensions
    frames.forEach(({ top, left, width, height }) => {
        const frame = createFrame(
            { x: left, y: top },
            { width: width, height: height }
        )
        frame.set({
            cellX: width / cellW,
            cellY: height / cellH,
            lockScalingFlip: true,
        })
        drawingCanvas.add(frame)
    })
}

function createFrame({ x, y }, { width, height } = { width: 0, height: 0 }) {
    const rect = new fabric.Rect({
        top: y,
        left: x,
        width,
        height,
        stroke: 'gray',
        borderStrokeWidth: borderStrokeWidth,
        fill: 'white',
        type: objectTypes.frame,
        strokeUniform: true,
        noScaleCache: false,
        objectCaching: false,
    })
    drawingCanvas.setActiveObject(rect)
    return rect
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
```